# Displaying popup window in JQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm using JQuery mobile, and I'm trying to display a popup window, but the popup simply don't show up. Here is what I've tried to do so far:

```
document.addEventListener("menubutton", function(){
    var template = $("<div data-role='popup' id='menu-option' "
        + "data-overlay-theme='a'>"
        + "<ul data-role='listview' data-inset='true' "
        + "style='min-width:210px;' data-theme='d'>"
        + "<li data-role='divider' data-theme='e'>Options</li>"
        + "<li><a>Setting</a></li>"
        + "<li><a>Refresh</a></li>"
        + "<li><a>Help</a></li>"
        + "<li><a>about</a></li>"
        + "<li><a id='exit-app'>Exit App</a></li>"
        + "</ul> </div>");


    template.appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer);                     
    template.popup();
    template.popup('open');

    }, false);
```

Comment: What device you are trying? menubutton event is not supported in all devices.

Answer (score 0):

Popup div should be appended to page div, it wont work if you add it to body or *pageContainer*. Also, you need to create it before you *open* it.

```
// append it to active page or a specific #page
template.appendTo($.mobile.activePage);

// create it and then open it
$("[data-role=popup]").popup().trigger("create").popup('open');
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/99sED/)**